# Trouble with Python Lambda Function

Tags: python, aws-lambda

Have the following simple lambda function created by terraform in AWS

```
import boto3
import os

region = 'eu-west-2'
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=region)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    instances = os.environ.get('instances')
    ec2.start_instances(InstanceIds=instances)
    print('started your instances: ' + str(instances))
```

instances = ["i-074efa1dca3049688"]

Getting the following error:

```
Response
{
  "errorMessage": "Parameter validation failed:\nInvalid type for parameter InstanceIds, value: [\"i-074efa1dca3049688\"], type: <class 'str'>, valid types: <class 'list'>, <class 'tuple'>",
  "errorType": "ParamValidationError",
  "requestId": "48c01f04-24ce-4398-a98a-f51e1160d6d5",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_start.py\", line 9, in lambda_handler\n    ec2.start_instances(InstanceIds=instances)\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 530, in _api_call\n    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 919, in _make_api_call\n    request_dict = self._convert_to_request_dict(\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 990, in _convert_to_request_dict\n    request_dict = self._serializer.serialize_to_request(\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/validate.py\", line 381, in serialize_to_request\n    raise ParamValidationError(report=report.generate_report())\n"
  ]
}
```

Am confused as to why the parameter validation is failing

Comment: It says why - that's a string (environment variables are always going to be) that just _looks_ like a list.

Answer (score 1):

instances is a string, you should trans it to list

```
import json
instances = json.loads(instances)
print(type(instances))
```

you can get

```
<class 'list'>
```

Answer (score 0):

os.environ.get returns a string, and it looks like start_instances wants a list of instances, so your instances variable will either be `"["i-074efa1dca3049688"]"` or just `"i-074efa1dca3049688"`.

you need to parse this to the list that you need.